# Struts 1 - Row submit

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1, struts-html, struts1

I'm having an issue with a Struts 1 form, which contains a logic:iterate in charge of creating rows, each with an input button. 
The problem comes up when I hit any of those submit buttons, the dynamic data is not properly being posted and the form doesn't have those values, here's an example:

```
<html:form action="/myAction" styleClass="centeredForm"  style="display:inline" >
  <td class="formLabel">City</td>
  <td class="formControl">
    <bean:define id="cities" name="myForm"
                 property="cities" type="java.util.Collection"/>
    <html:select styleClass="dashSelect" property="city">
      <html:option value="">All Cities</html:option>
      <html:options collection="cities"
                    property="id" labelProperty="value"/>
    </html:select>
  </td>

  ... Other elements ...

  <logic:iterate id="myObject" name="myForm" property="myObjects" indexId="index" type="com.test.MyObject">
      <% String rowClass = index.intValue() % 2 == 0 ? "even-row" : "odd-row"; %>
    <tr class="<%=rowClass%>">
      <td class="result-cell"><bean:write name="myObject" property="id" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="result-cell"><bean:write name="myObject" property="name" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="result-cell">
        <html:select styleClass="dashSelect" name="myObject" property="status">
          <html:option value="F">Disabled</html:option>
          <html:option value="T">Enabled</html:option>
        </html:select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <html:submit/>
      </td>
```

The "city" portion and the rest outside of the logic:iterate, come up just fine on "myForm", but "myObject" isn't. I even tried submitting this with a JavaScript function but wasn't able to get it properly working. 
Currently, what I have (That html:submit that I left as a reference) causes the POST to contain a bunch of "status" parameters and the proper values that I mentioned before.

Can anyone shed some light onto this?

Let me know if you need further information.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean; you're not using the `indexed` tags (see [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/faqs/indexedprops.html)) or nested tags, nor building indexed property names manually--I'm not entirely clear on what's not working, though. (Seems to be a lot of extra effort in some of the tags/beans, too; have you considered using JSP EL or at least the EL Struts tags if you're on an antiquated container?)

Comment: The problem is that when I hit submit, the form doesn't have "myObject" populated, which is the information for every row I create via the logic:iterate.
I'll take a look to the indexed tags in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using one single form, I've just used a form inside the logic:iterate, added indexes to the corresponding properties and used a Javascript function to obtain the rest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Logic Iterate**: Try do this way It may be help you.

```
<logic:iterate name="myForm" property="myObjects" id="myObjects" indexId="true">
  <tr>
   <td class="result-cell"><bean:write name="myObjects" property="id" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="result-cell"><bean:write name="myObjects" property="name"/>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <html:submit/>
      </td>    
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Hello subodh,
Unfortunately, bean:write doesn't have value or indexed attributes. :(
Were you meaning to use another one?

Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Oh!! Then what happens, if you are not using value and indexed, property Is it showing any error or what is the output? See my update answer try to do this, and still if any problem let me know.